# how to change the text of header(month) of SfDateRangePicker widget - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

I want to change the text of the header(month) cell.  [this text!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvCRl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hiding the default headers (headerHeight=0, viewHeaderHeight = 0) and adding the custom header you can add the required text. We have a KB documentation for the same. Please find the KB from the following link.

**KB link:**
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11427/how-to-customize-the-header-view-of-the-flutter-date-range-picker

Also, we have a KB documentation for customize the cell using cellBuilder. Please find the UG and KB documentation from the following link.

**UG link:**
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/daterangepicker/builders#cell-builder

**KB link:**
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12208/how-to-customize-the-date-range-picker-cells-using-builder-in-the-flutter-sfdaterangepicker